# DFS (.Net): GetSchemaInfo returns no typeInfos

Tags: documentum

I have a Documentum Developer Edition 6.6. I am using DFS (.Net Productivity Layer).
I have tried to call GetSchemaInfo method in Schema service. The method returns the following result:

Description:    "Default Schema"
Label:  "not implemented"
Name:   null
TypeInfos: empty list

Why the TypeInfos is empty? I expected it to contain list of all Types specified on that my Server (it has dozens of them)? Maybe I understand essence of the Schema not correctly? I though – as soon as my Content Server has Types, the GetSchemaInfo will return them in TypeInfos? Or something else is needed to have ‘Schema’ atop of the Types? What the "not implemented" mean in the returned Label?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include SchemaProfile { includeTypes = true } in the ServiceContext.
Using the .NET Productivity layer the code should look something like this:
[IServiceContextProperty].SetProfile(new SchemaProfile() { includeTypes = true });